# How to run active worker in background service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, nullpointerexception, worker

I have a **Worker Thread** class extends Thread and I add workers in queue in this class.I want to run one worker in background service.This is my service and onStartCommand methods

```
 protected WorkerThread workerThread;
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     if (this.looperThread.isAlive()) {
        this.looperThread.start(); }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

and I startService in my MainActivity,but I close the app I got an error like this **looperThread.start() Null point Exception** .How can I run worker in back service ? Thanks

Comment: tried `android.app.IntentService`?

Comment: so read documentation of `IntentService` - its what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Intent Service. You can put all your code that you want in worker thread inside it. Here is an example

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
        super("Cashback IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ....Your code that is to be executed in background goes here
    }
}
```